# Is there a concise way to "invert" an Option?

Tags: scala, option-type

Say I have a function that can take an optional parameter, and I want to return a `Some` if the argument is `None` and a `None` if the argument is `Some`:

```
def foo(a: Option[A]): Option[B] = a match {
  case Some(_) => None
  case None    => Some(makeB())
}
```

So what I want to do is kind of the inverse of `map`. The variants of `orElse` are not applicable, because they retain the value of `a` if it's present.

Is there a more concise way to do this than `if (a.isDefined) None else Some(makeB())`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use case for accepting an Option as a parameter? Typically I've always just dropped the Option's as parameters and called map on the option then pass it to the function which would take the unboxed option

Comment: I actually like the `if(a.isDefined) ...`: clear and as concise as it can get

Comment: In my current particular use case I'm generating X.509 certificates as test data, and want to generate and output a CA cert in addition to the subject cert _unless_ the subject cert is given as an argument.

Comment: It seems an odd API that accepts a `Some` but ignores what it contains.  That feels more like a Boolean. Can you explain the use case (especially what you do with the result)? Also, is `makeB()` pure? In that case, even odder.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Yubico/java-u2flib-server/blob/webauthn-cr/webauthn-server-core/src/test/scala/com/yubico/webauthn/test/TestAuthenticator.scala#L212-L232) is the use case. It's an internal API for generating test data. Notice how the method accepts an `attestationCertAndKey: Option[(X509Certificate, PrivateKey)]` and returns an `Option[X509Certificate]`, the latter of which (the CA certificate) is `Some` if and only if the former (the subject certificate) is `None`. In other words, if a subject cert is given it won't be signed, but if not given one will be generated and signed.

Comment: [Unbroken link to use case](https://github.com/Yubico/java-webauthn-server/blob/574425450b020a97594cd1e298859a60ffea831d/webauthn-server-core/src/test/scala/com/yubico/webauthn/TestAuthenticator.scala#L204-L224)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overview of this answer:

1. One-liner solution using `fold`
2. Little demo with the `fold`
3. Discussion of why the `fold`-solution *could* be just as "obvious" as the `if-else`-solution.

---

**Solution**

You can always use `fold` to transform `Option[A]` into whatever you want:

```
a.fold(Option(makeB())){_ => Option.empty[B]}
```

**Demo**

Here is a complete runnable example with all the necessary type definitions:

```
class A
class B
def makeB(): B = new B

def foo(a: Option[A]): Option[B] = a match {
  case Some(_) => None
  case None    => Some(makeB())
}

def foo2(a: Option[A]): Option[B] = 
  a.fold(Option(makeB())){_ => Option.empty[B]}

println(foo(Some(new A)))
println(foo(None))
println(foo2(Some(new A)))
println(foo2(None))
```

This outputs:

```
None
Some(Main$$anon$1$B@5fdef03a)
None
Some(Main$$anon$1$B@48cf768c)
```

---

**Why `fold` only *seems* less intuitive**

In the comments, @TheArchetypalPaul has commented that `fold` seems "lot less obvious" than the `if-else` solution. I agree, but I still think that it might be interesting to reflect on the reasons why that is.

I think that this is mostly an artifact resulting from the presence of special `if-else` syntax for booleans.

If there were something like a standard

```
def ifNone[A, B](opt: Option[A])(e: => B) = new {
  def otherwise[C >: B](f: A => C): C = opt.fold((e: C))(f)
}
```

syntax that can be used like this:

```
val optStr: Option[String] = Some("hello")

val reversed = ifNone(optStr) { 
  Some("makeB") 
} otherwise {
  str => None
}
```

and, more importantly, if this syntax was mentioned on the first page of every introduction to every programming language invented in the past half-century, then the `ifNone-otherwise` solution (that is, `fold`), would look much more natural to most people.

Indeed, the `Option.fold` method is the *eliminator* of the `Option[T]` type: whenever we have an `Option[T]` and want to get an `A` out of it, the most obvious thing to expect should be a `fold(a)(b)` with `a: A` and `b: T => A`. In contrast to the special treatment of booleans with the `if-else`-syntax (which is a mere convention), the `fold` method is very fundamental, the fact that it *must be there* can be derived from the first principles.

Comment: Yes, you can but `a.fold(Option(makeB())){_ => Option.empty[B]}` is lot less obvious (to me) than the `if`/`else` of the OP.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I'm afraid that the `if-else` is more "obvious" because you've simply got used to it. If you treat `Boolean` and `Option[T]` symmetrically, and do not give `Boolean` any preference because it's 50 years older, then this is what you get: `if(b) a1 else a2` is the canonical eliminator of `Boolean` which, given `a1: A` and `a2: A` can transform any `b: Boolean` into `A`. Analogously, `o.fold(a1)(a2)` with `a1: A`, `a2: T => A` is *the canonical eliminator* of `Option[T]`. If you have an `Option[T]` and want an `A`, the `fold` is absolutely the most canonical thing to expect.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul ... The asymmetry comes from the fact that `Boolean` is so extremely common that it got its own `if-else` syntactic sugar in the language definition. If for every boolean instead of `if (b) x else y` you would have to write `b.fold(x, y)`, then the `if-isEmpty-else`-construct proposed by the OP would translate into `o.isEmpty.fold(Option.empty[B], Option(makeB()))`, which is not really that much clearer than the direct `o.fold(Option(makeB())){_ => Option.empty[B]}`. It's all just because there is the `if-else` syntactic sugar for booleans.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I've incorporated your comments into my answer.

Comment: "It's's all just because there is the if-else syntactic sugar for booleans. " It's not "just". That syntacic sugar is what makes it obvious. "Canonical"  is not necessarily the same thing as "obvious" (and neithers is "intuitive").

Comment: Yes, "if/then/else" may be an historical thing but it's historically in programming languages exactly because the meaning is pretty obvious even before you've learnt much about the language - everyone is familiar with the idea even if not a programmer. I'm afraid I regard claims that "fold" (and other FP concepts) are more obviously more intuitive like the claims we used to hear about object-orientation being the way the world is: a confusion of the map with the terroitory.

Comment: In other words, your argument seems to be that if we remove the syntatic sugar that makes the if/then/else more obvious, then it is no longer more obvious. Which is true, but I tihnk misses the point.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I'm not sure what the point even is: you *find* the fold less obvious - that's completely alright, you are definitely not alone with that opinion (I myself would probably just write the `match-case`, because I find that more obvious). I've additionally added a remark about the fold being the canonical eliminator: that is, every possible function from `Option[T]` to `A` can be expressed through a `fold`. That's a mathematical statement. It does not claim anything about "obviousness" or "the world" or "the territory", it is just *true*. Whether it's useful is another question.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The original question of OP was not about the most "obvious" solutions either, it asked for a *concise* solution. I think just by counting characters one can verify that the `fold` is *shorter* than either the `match-case` and the `if-else`, so it satisfies the conciseness requirement. In your opinion it sacrifices clarity for conciseness: ok, I mostly agree with this opinion. But that was not the original question.

Answer (score 9):

fold is more concise than pattern matching

```
 val op:Option[B] = ...

 val inv = op.fold(Option(makeB()))(_ => None)
```

Comment: Nice idea, but if I try to compile it it gives: error: `object None does not take type parameters`. I couldn't get around it without writing out `Option` explicitly?..

Comment: Cool! That is indeed concise, but I'm not sure I'd rather read that than the `if (isDefined) ...` solution... :)

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with this definition `a.map(_ => None).getOrElse(Some(makeB()))`:

```
scala> def f[A](a: Option[A]) = a.map(_ => None).getOrElse(Some(makeB()))
f: [A](a: Option[A])Option[makeB]

scala> f(Some(44))
res104: Option[makeB] = None

scala> f(None)
res105: Option[makeB] = Some(makeB())
```

Comment: Notice that there is the identity `a.map(f).getOrElse(n) = a.fold(n)(f)`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Are you saying I just applied a `fold` law without even realize it? :P

Comment: Yep. Congratulations, you've reached the state where you are automatically inventing catamorphisms on-the-fly without even realizing it. Very good! :D That's what happens when you program too much haskell: "Oops, have I just accidentally reinvented F-Algebras?" ;)

Comment: Thanks :D! Hope to reach the state for anamorphisms soon! Haskell FTW

Comment: It's because `a.getOrElse(n) = a.fold(n)(identity)`. Actually, that's an interesting method to "rationally design an API": take the fold, if there are some gaps that can be plugged in by some canonical functions, then plug in canonical functions, rename the result as something. Never thought about `getOrElse` as about such a rationally constructed shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most concise and clearest might be `Option.when(a.isEmpty)(makeB)`